# SKShapeNode.fillColor not equal to original UIColor

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uicolor, skshapenode

I have just wasted many hours looking for an answer why below code gives not equal result:

```
let originalColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
let section = SKShapeNode(path: path.cgPath)
section.fillColor = originalColor
let isEqual = section.fillColor == originalColor //=> gives false
```

I don't have any idea, what's wrong with that. I have compared the color spaces and `UIColor`'s corresponding `CGColor` and only the `CGColor` has a different `hashValue`. But why is that? Above code should be working, it's pretty straightforward, what am I missing here?

**EDIT**
I have used below code to compare `UIColor`s:

```
extension SKColor {

static func !=(lhs: UIColor, rhs: UIColor) -> Bool {
    return !lhs.isEqualTo(rhs)
}

func isEqualTo(_ color: UIColor) -> Bool {
    var red1: CGFloat = 0, green1: CGFloat = 0, blue1: CGFloat = 0, alpha1: CGFloat = 0
    getRed(&red1, green:&green1, blue:&blue1, alpha:&alpha1)

    var red2: CGFloat = 0, green2: CGFloat = 0, blue2: CGFloat = 0, alpha2: CGFloat = 0
    color.getRed(&red2, green:&green2, blue:&blue2, alpha:&alpha2)

    return red1 == red2 && green1 == green2 && blue1 == blue2 && alpha1 == alpha2
}

}
```

The compare result for some other `UIColor` - instantiated the same way (red/green/blue with suffix 1 is the `fillColor` of the shape:

```
(lldb) po red1
0.8784313797950745

(lldb) po red2
0.8784313725490196

(lldb) po green1
0.10196078568696976

(lldb) po green2
 0.10196078431372549

(lldb) po blue1
0.30980393290519714

(lldb) po blue2
0.30980392156862746
```

Comment: You're making a pretty big assumption about how UIColor equality works. Here's an idea: try fetching and testing explicitly the `red`, `green`, `blue`, and `alpha` components of the colors. That way what we are comparing is CGFloats, and we _know_ how that works.

Comment: Oooooh here's another point to think about: maybe the color you are giving is reduced to a gray behind the scenes?

Comment: Hey @matt thanks for quick reply :) I have checked that also with the code above - editted my question, please have a look. It gives different values in terms of `CGFloat` components.

Comment: OK, but now you face the problem of float comparison. These color values are the same to 7 or 8 significant digits, and that's far beyond the realm of any perceptible difference. So the colors are equal to all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
return red1 == red2 && green1 == green2 && blue1 == blue2 && alpha1 == alpha2
```

To this:

```
return Float(red1) == Float(red2) && 
    Float(green1) == Float(green2) && 
    Float(blue1) == Float(blue2) && 
    Float(alpha1) == Float(alpha2)
```

Comment: This is working! :) Thank you very much. However, it seems to me like an issue in iOS framework or even Swift - we can't see the internals of Apple's framework, hard to verify. Above results are different for the same compare technique and same input. Good catch @matt to try to reduce the float precision. Now the results are the same :-)

Comment: I have tried the same with comparing `UIColor`s instantiated, but not assigned to `SKShapeNode.fillColor` and it worked (before making your change in the comparing part of the code.) :)

Comment: I am still wondering, why this is happening with the `fillColor` property of the `SKShapeNode` instance.

Comment: Good question. :) But I think we both have the same guess: behind the scenes, perhaps the color is in fact being reduced to its Float equivalent. — Also, even though UIColor and SKColor are typealiases for one another, would it have made a difference to create your color as an SKColor instead of a UIColor?

Comment: Yes, I know about the alias for SKColor, but just to be sure I have tried with UIColor and SKColor - same thing. I thought that maybe, behind the scenes, there is a class name check, but clearly that's not the case.

Comment: There are a few spots in the Sprite Kit API where Apple can't decide to use a float or double on a lot of  floating point variables, and will cast between the two. You will see the influx of number for almost anything SpriteKit related, your best bet is to always try to cast to Float when doing a comparison on any floating number to ensure a better comparison.